# header ("Location: for FTP not working in IE

Tags: php

I have a very simple HTML login form, where users can enter their username to connect to an FTP server.

```
$url= 'ftp://'.$_POST['username'].'@domainname.com/';
header ("Location: $url");
exit();
```

The code works fine with Mozilla, it is only IE8, where I encounter problems.  I can redirect to a page if I use HTTP, it seems to be the FTP that I am having problems with.

Answer (score 1):

On some browsers, you cannot redirect to another protocol, such as FTP.  In fact, some browsers are unable to do FTP at all, but that is not the problem here.

You will have to redirect using some other means.  I would recommend a JavaScript approach.

Comment: `window.location = 'ftp://someuser@domainname.com'`

Answer (score 0):

in js from PHP:

```
$scriptTag = '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "ftp://'.$validatedUserName.'@domainname.com/";</script>';
print $scriptTag;
```

Comment: That's not very safe.  You're opening yourself to XSS!

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  I really do not know much about js, and I have read on other posts that if a person has js turned off, then using js won't work.  Is that true for your above code fix?

Comment: @Brad, did you not just write that in another comment? how is js supposed to be executed if its not in script tags? if you're talking about validation, sure, you have a point, but he should be validating regardless of what we tell him to do

Comment: @Kristian, What you have there *is* within `<script>` tags.  It's trivial to close your quotes and execute arbitrary code, and insert extra HTML.  Even if it wasn't, if you don't properly escape your data, you could insert your own `<script>` tags.  What you show is not enough.  You need to properly encode this stuff.

Comment: @user1572323, If your users have JavaScript turned off, then JavaScript doesn't work.  Plain and simple.  The 3rd method is to use a meta refresh, but that isn't ideal either.  I'd guess that JavaScript is going to work for more users than meta refresh.

Comment: ok, well the JavaScript worked and all is good!  Thank you and thanks for being so quick.  I appreciate it!